# Border around image when radiobutton is checked for that image

Tags: html, css, reactjs, angular

I am trying to add a border or glow around an image when the radio button associated with that image is selected. This is part of an angular program. The problem is that nothing happens with my image when I select the associated radio button. I have tried changing some properties of the image but that is also difficult.

My html is as follows:

```
<div>
   <title>Quiz Page</title>
   <div class="quiz-container has-text-white">
       <h2>Quiz Program</h2>
       <span> {{timeLeft}} </span>
       <div class="card has-text-black">
           <form *ngIf="answer_form" [formGroup]="answer_form" (ngSubmit)="checkAnswers()" id="answer_form">
               <div *ngFor="let question of questions;index as idx">
                   <h3>Question {{idx+1}}:</h3>
                   <p>{{question.Question}}</p>
                   <div class="field">
                       <div class="control" *ngFor="let answer of answers">
                           <div class="fl" *ngIf="answer.QuestionID === question._id">
                               <label class="radio">
                                   <input type="radio" class="imgradio" value="{{answer._id}}" formControlName="{{question._id}}">
                                   <img class="max-size-image" src={{answer.Answer}} alt="">
                               </label>
                           </div>
                       </div>
                   </div>
               </div>
               <button class="button is-primary is-rounded" *ngIf="!boolTimesUp">Submit</button>
           </form>
           <p id="time-left">{{timeLeftDisplay}}</p>
           <p id="score">{{scoreDisplay}}</p>
       </div>
   </div>
```

and my styling as follows:

```
.quiz-container {
    background: rgb(4, 82, 137);
    background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(4, 82, 137, 1) 0%, rgba(22, 0, 84, 1) 50%, rgba(82, 1, 63, 1) 100%);
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    min-height: 100vh;
    max-height: fit-content;
}

h2 {
    font-size: 24px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

p {
    font-size: 16px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}


#countdown {
    font-size: 24px;
    text-align: center;
}

#submit-btn {
    margin-top: 20px;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.result {
    margin-top: 15px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.card {
    margin-left: 20%;
    margin-right: 20%;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .15);
    backdrop-filter: blur(5px);
}

.quest {
    font-size: x-large;
    font-weight: bold;
}

input[type=radio]:checked ~ img {
    border: 2px solid red;
}
```

but this just results in nothing happening to the images when I select any of the radio buttons.

Comment: I think this is just simply a case of missing quotes about the value in the type attribute selector.

Comment: Have you tried removing `:checked` from the selector to verify your style will actually apply to the image? The image has class `max-size-image`, which is not included in the CSS you posted, so maybe that class is overriding the border you're trying to apply?

Answer (score 0):

The sibling selector (~) selects all subsequent siblings, however, it does not select elements across parent/child boundaries. In your HTML, input and img are not siblings, but nested within different parent elements (label and div respectively), thus your CSS rule does not apply.

You can create a class in your CSS and use Angular's property binding feature to add this class to the image when the radio button is selected. Let's call this class selected.

CSS Code:

```
.selected {
    border: 2px solid red;
}
```

Then, in your HTML, add the class conditionally to the img tag:

```
<img class="max-size-image" 
     src={{answer.Answer}} 
     alt="" 
     [class.selected]="answer_form.value[question._id] === answer._id">
```

This binds the class selected to the img tag when the condition inside the brackets is true. The condition checks if the selected value of the formControl (i.e., the radio button selected) is equal to the answer._id. When it is, it will add the class selected to the img tag, which adds a border to your image. I'm assuming that unique ._id's for each answer.

Comment: Input and img look like siblings to me, both within a label element.